# Django : Updating row data in sqlite without reloading page

Tags: django, sqlite

I am displaying a random image from the database. After the image is displayed, it's count should be set to 1 the moment it gets displayed so it is not used again. 
I have tried to write a view function which tries to change the count when the image is selected for display. There is no update form or button click involved.

**views.py**

````
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from .models import Image
import random
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    y= random.randint(0,10)
    p = Image.objects.all()[y]
    if (p.p_image_count==0):
        p_img = Image.objects.all()[y]
        Image.objects.all()[y].p_image_count += 1
        # Image.save(self)

    lst = [p.s_image1, p.s_image2, p.s_image3, p.s_image3, p.s_image4, p.s_image5]
    x = random.randint(0,4)
    tmp =[]
    for i in range(0,3):
        p = Image.objects.all()[random.randint(0,14)]
        tmps=[p.s_image1, p.s_image2, p.s_image3, p.s_image3, p.s_image4, p.s_image5]
        tmp.append(tmps[random.randint(0,4)])



    s_img = [lst[x]]+ tmp
    random.shuffle(s_img)




    return render(request,'index.html',{"p_img":p_img, "s_img": s_img, 'media_url':settings.MEDIA_URL})```
````

**models.py** - Image model

```
class Image(models.Model):

    p_image = models.ImageField(max_length=255,upload_to='p_image',default='NULL', blank='NULL')
    p_image_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    s_image1 = models.ImageField(max_length=255,upload_to='s_image')
    s_image1_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    s_image2 = models.ImageField(max_length=255,upload_to='s_image',default='NULL', blank='NULL')
    s_image2_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    s_image3 = models.ImageField(max_length=255,upload_to='s_image',default='NULL', blank='NULL')
    s_image3_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    s_image4 = models.ImageField(max_length=255,upload_to='s_image',default='NULL', blank='NULL')
    s_image4_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    s_image5 = models.ImageField(max_length=255,upload_to='s_image',default='NULL', blank='NULL')
    s_image5_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    #if image displayed currently , set flag to true
```

Comment: if p_image_count == 0, then you will show rest of five images. why are you using flags. How many image will you show at once?

Comment: @sandeep i am trying to make a game where we match answers given by people on images. so if a flag is set to true that means an answer for that image exists and the next player should be given that image so his/her answer can be matched after they submit theirs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got solved after I learnt to use .save() properly. Actually I was updating p_image_count by using Image.save()

The correct way to do it was -

```
Image.objects.all()[y].save()
```

> .save() needs the row object that is updated.

Thank you for your time! :)